# Feign Client throws unknown host exception with DNS name

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have created Spring boot application and consuming REST API's developed and deployed on other server with DNS name.

```
 @FeignClient(url="${env.app.crm.url}", value= "crm-feign-client", path ="/CRM/API", configuration = CRMFeignConfiguration.class)
@Headers("Content-Type: application/json")
public interface CRMFeignClients {
```

Success scenarios:

1. when I run application locally by consuming API's using feign client with DNS name.
2. when I run application locally by consuming API's using feign client with IP address.
3. Deployed my application on server by consuming API's using feign client with IP address.

Failure case:

1. when I deploy my application on server by consuming API's using feign client with DNS name it is giving unknown host exception

Below is the log:

```
**feign.RetryableException: <HOST NAME**> executing POST http://<**HOST NAME AND CONTEXT PATH**>/UpdateCustomer
        at feign.FeignException.errorExecuting(FeignException.java:268)
        at feign.SynchronousMethodHandler.executeAndDecode(SynchronousMethodHandler.java:131)
        at feign.SynchronousMethodHandler.invoke(SynchronousMethodHandler.java:91)
        at feign.ReflectiveFeign$FeignInvocationHandler.invoke(ReflectiveFeign.java:100)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy176.updateCustomer(Unknown Source)
        at com.kafd.outbound.services.KAFDCrmService.callCustomerUpdateService(KAFDCrmService.java:107)
        at com.kafd.outbound.services.KAFDBackgroundService.CustomerDataPush(KAFDBackgroundService.java:81)
        at com.kafd.outbound.services.KAFDBackgroundService$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$add32094.invoke(<generated>)
        at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:218)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:793)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:763)
        at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.AsyncExecutionInterceptor.lambda$invoke$0(AsyncExecutionInterceptor.java:115)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
**Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException**: <**MY HOST NAME**>
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:184)
        at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
        at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:175)
        at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:432)
        at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:527)
        at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.<init>(HttpClient.java:211)
        at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:308)
        at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:326)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(HttpURLConnection.java:1169)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect0(HttpURLConnection.java:1105)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:999)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.connect(HttpURLConnection.java:933)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1283)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1258)
        at feign.Client$Default.convertAndSend(Client.java:208)
        at feign.Client$Default.execute(Client.java:105)
        at feign.SynchronousMethodHandler.executeAndDecode(SynchronousMethodHandler.java:121)
```

Answer (score 0):

I know it's been over a year at this point but I came across a very similar problem.
This might not be the solution but I'm still sharing my resolution in case it helps or it helps someone else.

In the annotation `@FeignClient` in the `url` property it wasn't enough to put just the host name. I also had to include the name of the service I was trying to reach.

So in this case your `env.app.crm.url` property should look like something like this:

`env.app.crm.url=<your-hosts-ip>/<service-name>`